# Unable to install pandas - InsecurePlatformWarning error

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, pyscripter

I am using pyScripter 2.7.5 and tring to install pandas using command "pip install pandas" but it is showing the below error:

> Collecting pandas
>   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:318:
>   SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI
>   (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this
>   platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS
>   certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a
>   newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
>   SNIMissingWarning
>   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:122:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of
>   Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
>   InsecurePlatformWarning   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/pandas/: There was a problem confirming
>   the ssl certificate: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version -
>   skipping   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   pandas (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pandas
>   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:122:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of
>   Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
>   InsecurePlatformWarning

Please help me to resolve this as after installing I can solve the below error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Jaya Learning\Code
>   test\excel_diffence.py", line 85, in 
>       import pandas as pd ImportError: No module named pandas

Comment: I think the problem might be just be on this line`You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this`. Have you thought about upgrading to python 3

Comment: Could you please paste the output and error message within a **code block** and preserve the line endings, so we don't get a wall of text without a structure. *(the suggested edit just wraps it all in a quote block, that that doesn't preserve the line endings nor does it give structure to the content within the quoted block)*

Comment: Question: Are you doing it exactly as in your post: `pip install panda` or are you using `pip install pandas`? Because the 's' at the end is important

Comment: I think they are installing `pandas` correctly but the problem could be proxy. Make sure you are not behind a firewall.

Comment: Sorry the typing error in comment it is "pip install pandas" still the error is same as above.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this SSL error?